# Create new language in mid-project

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Was requested by the client a new language to add to the project in sitecore. I'm having some issues with that,

I've created the language, however all the renderings are empty for the new language.
There's no version assigned to any item for the new language also.

I tried to do a trick that was to export the English language and open the generated xml file and rename the tags ,  to the requested language and then import. But when I'm trying to import it, shows as I was importing English language and not the new one.

How can I create a new language with all the renderings and content (even if it goes to english when empty string, I know it's default procedure) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell script for that.

See e.g. this blog http://www.coreblimeysitecore.com/blog/create-language-versions-using-sitecore-powershell/

Sample code is

```
Add-ItemLanguage -Path "master:\sitecore\content" -Language "en" -TargetLanguage "de-AT","de-de","en-za","fi-fi","fr-be","it-it","pl-pl","ru-ru","sv-se","fr-fr" -IfExist OverwriteLatest  -IgnoredFields ""
```

And here is a very similar question on http://sitecore.stackexchange.com site:

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/create-new-language-version-for-content-branch

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it doesn't do what I thought.

It translated the item (I did recursive method) to different language, but the website components are only showing in english. If I change to other it's an empty page.

Comment: Have you translated datasources of those components as well?

Comment: Yes, I translated everything - page items and datasources.
They all have multiple language versions, but the website in other languages than english still blank.

Should I translate the placeholders and rendering elements?
Other thing is that when I publish the website in context it only shows English.

Comment: Have you added the language from the Sitecore `Control Panel`? http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3172/adding-deleting-languages-from-control-panel

Comment: Yes, I added just after I wrote my last comment.

When I publish it appears the language (portuguese). However in the items I have the language as below:
- Portuguese (Portugal: português (Portugal) , which was the translate made by the powershell
- Portuguese : português

When I go to the website and put /pt  it shows me empty page if I put /en it shows me all the items